# React Native with UI Kitten icons results in a null object reference on Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I'm using UI Kitten library for my React Native app UI, and when I add their icon pack the Android app errors, iOS works fine.

Android gets:

```bash
Attempt to invoke virtual method `int java.lang.Integer.intValue()` on a null object reference
```

The `App.tsx`:

```js
import {EvaIconsPack} from '@ui-kitten/eva-icons';

export default () => (
<>
  <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack} />
  <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={{...eva.light, ...theme}}>
    <Layout style={styles.layout}>
      <Button accessoryLeft={<Icon name="facebook" />}>
        Login with Facebook
      </Button>
    </Layout>
  </ApplicationProvider>
</>
);
```

This line is the problem:

```js
<Icon name="facebook" />
```

When I remove it and leave the `Button` as

```js
<Button>
  Login with Facebook
</Button>
```

Android works again.

[image: android error]

Any ideas?

Comment: can you try 

`<Button accessoryLeft={(props) => (<Icon  {...props} name="facebook" />)}>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to provide a functional component like

```
<Button accessoryLeft={(props) => (<Icon  {...props} name="facebook" />)}>
```